# Allow LEX Bot take any input from IVR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am building a CTI integrated with Salesforce and one of the requirements is to allow the customer to give detailed service feedback. I need to get the transcript of the voice input to send to Salesforce.

The main problem I am facing is that I am not being able to get the transcript from the user to store it in a variable.

Could this be achieved with Lex Bot v1 or v2 and access the transcript?

Thank you very much!

PD:

- I have tried to do it with Lex Bot v1 but I cannot write the transcript in the Slot.
- I have tried to do it with Lex Bot v2 but when it is invoked from Contact Flow, I get an error.